# Connecting Druid with MySQL

Tags: mysql, druid

I finish setting up Druid on my computer by reading [quickstart guide](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html). I do setup MySQL extension by reading [MySQL Metadata Store](http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/mysql.html) as well.

But, when I sign to mysql to

```
mysql -u druid -p dirud
```

I got `druid` table only.I don't have any data that I imported with the following command via example.

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/wikiticker-index.json localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task
```

I saw `Success` status on Druid console `http://localhost:8090/console.html` as well.

The following is my `common.runtime.properties` for mysql setup

```
druid.metadata.storage.type=mysql
druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/druid
druid.metadata.storage.connector.user=druid
druid.metadata.storage.connector.password=diurd
```

Is something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Is it you are mistaking database name "druid" with table name?

Comment: MySQL is meatstore for druid.MySQL will store inforamtion about druid_dataSource,druid_segments,druid_pendingSegments and more info about druid. You can check this link for querying your data http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/querying.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mistaken in understanding druid. Mysql is used just for storing the metadata of the segments and not the actual log data. The druid ingestion here must be using your local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql or postgresql just use to store the metabase about jobs/task info,the ingestion data was be store in your local filesytem \hdfs \S3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Druid uses MySQL for reading and writing segment Metadata. It's highly inadvisable to use the same MySql database. An existing set up can be used by Druid. If I were you I would restrict Druid tables to druid user. And create a separate user for other application tables.